# Django - Disable form button during calculation

Tags: jquery, django

In a webpage the user fill a form and then he obtained an excel file.
I'd like to disable the buttons until the download is finished to prevent the user to presses them multiple times.

I tried this code:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('submitted')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $(this).find(':submit').html('<i>Attendi...</i>');
        $(this).addClass('submitted');
    }
});
```

But the buttons stay disable until I refresh the page.
The final chunk of the Django view code is this:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
wb.save(response)
return response
```

There is some way to re-abilitate the buttons or to force the page to reload after the download is started/finished?

Comment: yes there is. so when the button is clicked you could send an ajax/xhr request to your python backend which triggers your function and when the function is done, (`ajax...success: function(data) {...`" you enable the button again via JS. A cheap option B would be to set a timer `setTimeout(....removeClass('submitted');, 3000)` where you choose a default time to reset the button, it wouldnt be accurate but easy to implement...

Comment: The problem is that with some choices the calculation take 5 seconds, with other 3 minutes. So i Can't use this solution

Comment: I'm going to try the first way that you propose to me, could you help me in that one?